# django runserver hangs in docker-compose up but runs correctly in docker-compose run

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose

## Edit

Adding --ipv6 to the command, while not properly configured for, seem to surpass the point where the process hangs.

[image]

## Problem

- Calling **docker-compose up** executes runserver but hangs at some point after printing the current time.

[image: docker-compose up]

- Calling **docker-compose run -p 8000:8000 web python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000** also execute the server, but does so succesfully and can be reached at 192.168.99.100:8000.

[image: docker-compose run -p 8000:8000 web python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000]

## Questions

How come I can run the server directly from docker-compose in my shell but not from the .yml file?

To me, the content of the .yml file and the docker-compose run line from the shell are strikingly similar.

The only difference I can think of would perhaps be permissions at some level required to properly start a django server, but I don't know how to address that. Docker runs on a windows 8.1 machine. The shared folder for my virtual machine is the default c:\Users.

## Files

My folder contain a fresh django project as well as these docker files. I've tampered with different versions of python and django but the result is the same. I've cleaned up my images and containers between attempts using

```
docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)
docker rmi $(docker images -q)
```

*docker-compose.yml*

```
version: '3'
services:
    web:
        build: .
        command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
        volumes:
            - .:/code
        ports:
            - "8000:8000"
```

*Dockerfile*

```
FROM python:3.6-alpine
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
ADD requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ADD . /code/
```

*requirements.txt*

```
Django>=1.8,<2.0
```

## System

My operative system is windows 8.1

Comment: Why are you binding on localhost:8080 in your dockerfile instead of 0.0.0.0:8080?

Comment: Oh, that should be 0.0.0.0:8000. It still hangs in the same manner however. I just forgot to change it back after some testing.

Comment: what if you remove `volumes:
            - .:/code` in your compose file

Comment: removing `volumes: - .:/code` from my compose file and running it still result in the server hanging on start up. 

I listed the directory (`ls -l`) with volumes, without volumes and from the run command and what I noticed was that with volumes and the run command listed the same files with identical permissions (`-rwxrwxrwx`), whereas without volumes the permissions were `-rwxr-xr-x`. I don't know if this has any significance.

Comment: If I add the line `user: root` the permissions seem to match even without `volumes`, though it still hangs.

Answer (score 4):

I was hit by this issue myself and it seems that you need to allocate a tty and a stdin to your container in order to make `runserver` work:

```
  python:
    image: my-image:latest
    stdin_open: true # docker run -i
    tty: true # docker run -t
    build:
      context: ..
      dockerfile: docker/Dockerfile
```

Comment: `stdin_open: true` and `tty: true` also fixed hang in `http.server`/`BaseHTTPRequestHandler`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and could not get it to do anything else. However when i went to the ip of the docker machine `docker-machine ip` it returned 192.168.99.100, then by going to 192.168.99.100:8000 my docker container started receiving the requests